# Можно ли одновременно держать java 8 и java 9?

Tags: java, java-9

Есть Java 8 , Java 9 и к ним JDK 8 и JDK 9.
Нужно ли удалить одну из версий, чтобы не возникало никаких сбоев?

Интересуюсь, потому что есть одно java приложение, которое было создано на другом компьютере не запускается на моем. Возможно, в этом дело. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно, только в переменных путях PATH можно будет только одно держать, чтобы другую java запускать понадобится батник, в котором будет путь к той джаве прописан

Comment: В принципе держать младшую версию нет никакой надобности, потому что Java делает особый упор на обратной совместимости, то есть более новая версия Java будет делать все то же, что и старая и еще немножко нового.

Comment: @pavlofff Ява-то будет делать, а какой-нибудь дебильный апплет не будет запускаться, потому что ему подавай исключительно шестую (случай из жизни).

Comment: @Эникейщик вот кажется у меня эта проблема ! не запускается маленькое приложение. Возможно ли как-то обойти эту проблему ? или нужно узнать версию, на которой она создавалась и затем установить ?

Comment: @OlegKhegay Нужно запустить из командной строки и посмотреть какую ошибку выдает. Что-то вроде ``java путь/к/приложению``

Comment: @pavlofff обратная совместимость у них так себе, на самом деле, по крайней мере, в java9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Кроме уже данных ответов/советов хочется упомянуть такие инструменты, как [jabba](https://github.com/shyiko/jabba) и [sdkman](http://sdkman.io/), которые предназначены именно для безболезненной установки и переключения различных версий JDK и сопутствующих инструментов. В случае их использования все телодвижения сводятся к одной команде в консоли.

Answer (score 4):

- Если у вас установлены две версии java, это не принесет проблем(кроме этих https://www.java.com/ru/download/faq/remove_olderversions.xml, но это скорее рекомендации для обычных пользователей, а не разработчиков). Вы можете выбирать, какую из них использовать как для компиляции, так и для запуска приложения: нужно изменить **PATH**, либо **указать полный путь** до исполняемой программы:
  `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\javac"` - вызов компилятора Java 8
  `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\java"` - запуск приложения на Java 8
  `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.9.0_160\bin\javac"` - вызов компилятора Java 9
  `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\java"` - запуск приложения на Java 9
  Для того, чтобы избежать вашей проблемы, приложение может поставляться вместе с JRE, для которого оно разрабатывалось.
- По поводу совместимости Java 8 и Java 9.Стоит почитать про Java 9 **Jigsaw** https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-9-migration-guide/

Comment: если можно тупой вопрос, где следует прописывать импорты к программам ? Прям в коде в главном классе ?

Comment: полное имя класса выглядит так java.util.ArrayList. Например import java.util.ArrayList позволит использовать класс, не указывая пакеты: ArrayList. Импорт не подключает новый класс к твоей программе, а только позволяет указывать сокращееный вариант имени класса. Ты можешь не писать import и использовать полные имена: java.util.List<String> list = new java.util.ArrayList<>();

Answer (score 1):

можно, если осторожно :)

а если серьезно, то к сожалению приходится почти все время "держать" несколько версий в связи с неполной совместимостью.

как уже упоминалось в комментариях, основную (не обязательно самую свежую) версию вы прописываете в путях, а другие используете в загрузчиках или ярлыках конкретных приложений.

если у вас проблема с конкретным приложением, прикрепите логи или, если до логов добраться нет возможности, хотя бы скриншот выдаваемой ошибки.